# Error "Undefined reference to win main16

Tags: c++

I'm having an error in this simple program ... I get a windows warning which has the following message

`"Launching SDL basic.exe has encountered a problem. The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist."`

In the console  i get the following error "Undefined reference to `winmain16`. I have linked the header file and a library as well...I was using code blocks and i recently changed ide to eclipse so i want your answers as detailed and simple as possible...
My OS is Windows 7 64-bit...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "!!Hello World!!"<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is my first step into graphic programs after having downloaded sdl

Comment: you don't need to comment, you can edit your post. And please provide more details in the tags. Which Windows version do you target ?

Comment: Next time search before asking.

Comment: Sorry ...im new to this ...i was searching for a long time ...and i didnt find any questions that suited to my situation....i tried some of the things that was suggested in other questions that failed to change the error or produced more though...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide something like this:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
);
```

This is the "real" [main entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) into your program.